# Spring CLoud Task

Tags: java, task, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

is there a way to pass an task result as input to other tasks, like in the image below. Sounds easy, but I can't find anything on the Internet. I don't want to use queues or other mechanisms to do this, Im looking for a task "native" way.
[image]

I found this example, which I think it in this case **strings** represent the input for the task but I cant figure out how to produce the output to send to the next task/s

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringCloudTaskTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudTaskTestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner() {
        return new HelloWorldCommandLineRunner();
    }

    public static class HelloWorldCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

        @Override
        public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("TASK args: "+Arrays.toString(strings));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring Cloud Data Flow, you can use the [tasklauncher-dataflow](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tasklauncher-dataflow) out of the box stream `sink` application. In your case, a task application can send the [LaunchRequest](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tasklauncher-dataflow/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-task-launcher-dataflow/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/task/launcher/dataflow/sink/LaunchRequest.java#L32) to the `tasklauncher-dataflow` sink application to launch the other task application with the given properties. You can find more detail on this [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-launch-tasks-from-stream)